# Raspberry Pi 3b+ as a wireless access point: nl80211 driver initialization failed

Tags: raspbian, wifi, hostapd

I'm trying to set up a Raspberry Pi 3b+ (running Raspbian Stretch) as a wireless access point (using the built-in wireless interface) following [the official documentation](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point.md).

After setting up `/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf` and running `hostapd -d /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf` I get the following:

```
root@godzilla:/etc/init.d# hostapd -d /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf 
random: Trying to read entropy from /dev/random
Configuration file: /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
rfkill: initial event: idx=0 type=1 op=0 soft=0 hard=0
nl80211: Using driver-based roaming
nl80211: TDLS supported
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:1
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:5
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:2
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:4
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:6
nl80211: Using driver-based off-channel TX
nl80211: Supported vendor command: vendor_id=0x1018 subcmd=1
nl80211: Use separate P2P group interface (driver advertised support)
nl80211: Enable multi-channel concurrent (driver advertised support)
nl80211: use P2P_DEVICE support
nl80211: Disable use_monitor with device_ap_sme since no monitor mode support detected
nl80211: interface wlan0 in phy phy0
nl80211: Set mode ifindex 3 iftype 3 (AP)
nl80211: Setup AP(wlan0) - device_ap_sme=1 use_monitor=0
nl80211: Subscribe to mgmt frames with AP handle 0x1576038 (device SME)
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x1576038 match=
nl80211: Register frame command failed (type=208): ret=-22 (Invalid argument)
nl80211: Register frame match - hexdump(len=0): [NULL]
nl80211: Could not configure driver mode
nl80211: deinit ifname=wlan0 disabled_11b_rates=0
nl80211: Remove monitor interface: refcount=0
nl80211: Remove beacon (ifindex=3)
netlink: Operstate: ifindex=3 linkmode=0 (kernel-control), operstate=6 (IF_OPER_UP)
nl80211: Set mode ifindex 3 iftype 2 (STATION)
nl80211: Teardown AP(wlan0) - device_ap_sme=1 use_monitor=0
nl80211 driver initialization failed.
hostapd_interface_deinit_free(0x1574cd8)
hostapd_interface_deinit_free: num_bss=1 conf->num_bss=1
hostapd_interface_deinit(0x1574cd8)
wlan0: interface state UNINITIALIZED->DISABLED
hostapd_bss_deinit: deinit bss wlan0
wlan0: AP-DISABLED 
hostapd_cleanup(hapd=0x15759a0 (wlan0))
hostapd_free_hapd_data: Interface wlan0 wasn't started
hostapd_interface_deinit_free: driver=(nil) drv_priv=(nil) -> hapd_deinit
hostapd_interface_free(0x1574cd8)
hostapd_interface_free: free hapd 0x15759a0
hostapd_cleanup_iface(0x1574cd8)
hostapd_cleanup_iface_partial(0x1574cd8)
hostapd_cleanup_iface: free iface=0x1574cd8
```

`/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf` looks like this:

```
interface=wlan0
driver=nl80211
ssid=example
hw_mode=g
channel=7
wmm_enabled=0
macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=1
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
wpa=2
wpa_passphrase=example
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
```

How do I make this work?

Comment: your wpa2 passphrase is at least 8 characters long?

Comment: Yes, it is (it's currently 9 characters).

Comment: ok. just wanted to check, if you maybe actually had used example as password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this was a kernel version issue.

I had previously used `rpi-update` to update the installed kernel (to 4.14.90-v7+).  When I revert back to the stock kernel (4.14.79-v7+), things work as documented.